# Moving selection (only) of selected rows between columns

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I need to move selection (only, no data) of multiple rows from column A to column B in LibreOffice Calc. Any idea?

I have a price list:

```
| id | name    | description   | price   |
|----|---------|---------------|--​-------|
| 1  | GTX960  | GTX960 Desc.  | $200.00 |
| 2  | GTX1060 | GTX1060 Desc. | $350.00 |
| 3  | GTX1070 | GTX1070 Desc. | $650.00 |
```

I want to select name where id = 1 and id = 3 and then copy values to CSV sheet. Next I want to move the selection to price column and copy its values to CSV. I don't want to select from the beginning.

Comment: Please explain more clearly, perhaps with an example.  It may also help to describe why this is needed.  What is a "selection of selected rows?"  Is this different from normal cut and paste?  Explain what you have tried so far, and any attempt at looking online for an answer.

Comment: I have a price list:

| **id** | **name**       | **description**         | **price** |
|-------|------------------|--------------------------|------------|
| 1      | GTX960        | GTX960 Desc.        | $200.00 |
| 2      | GTX1060      | GTX1060 Desc.      | $350.00 |
| 3      | GTX1070      | GTX1070 Desc.      | $650.00 |

I want to select name where id = 1 and id = 3 and then copy values to CSV sheet. Next I want to move the selection to `price` column and copy its values to CSV. I don't want to select from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to work with selections described [here](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Selection_Mode) and [here](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Shortcut_Keys_for_Spreadsheets), but they are based on extending the selection rather than moving it.

It sounds like what you are trying to accomplish can be done with [VLOOKUP](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#VLOOKUP).

[image: vlookup example]

To do this, in cell G2 enter the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(F2,$A$2:$D$4,2)
```

The formula for H2 is the same except that it uses the index for the price column:

```
=VLOOKUP(F2,$A$2:$D$4,4)
```

Then drag these formulas down to row 3.  Finally, copy the IDs to column F that need to be grabbed.